# How do I move an S3 "Deep Glacier Archive" object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a number of "Deep Glacier Archive" class objects in the root level of my Amazon S3 bucket.

As the number of objects grows, I've added some top-level folders to the same bucket that I'd like to move the other objects into for organizational reasons. While I can add new objects to these folders, I've noticed that the "Move" action option is grayed out while when I have existing objects selected.

Is there a way that I can move these glacier objects into the other folders in the same bucket? (I'm using the Amazon AWS S3 web console interface.)

Comment: Have you check s3 lifecycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects cannot be 'moved' in Amazon S3. Doing so actually involves performing a `copy` and then `delete`.

The S3 management console is unable to move/copy an object with a `Glacier` storage class because the data is not immediately available. Instead, you should:

- **Restore** the object (Charges might apply)
- Once restored, perform the move/copy

Comment: This answers my question, thanks John. I do have a follow-up question though: right now my glacier object appears to be restored (I'm seeing a "restoration complete" message with an expiration date of April 12th), but I still don't seem to be able to copy the object using the bucket view. Do I need to download and re-upload the object, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you able to download it? If so, you should be able to copy it. Perhaps the S3 management console won't let you 'copy' an object with a Glacier storage class, but you can probably use the AWS CLI to copy it.

Comment: With the object selected the download button is active, so I believe I can. But when I open the "actions" menu with that same object selected, the "Copy" option is disabled. Interestingly the "Initiate Restore" option is still enabled, even though clicking into the object view shows the "Restoration complete" message. (I may have to start looking into the AWS CLI.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to first **restore** the objects and wait around 48h until the process completes (you can do that directly from the management console). Once it is done you should see the download button enabled in the console and a countdown of the days you set them to be available.

Then you can move them using the AWS CLI with:

```
aws s3 mv "s3://SOURCE" "s3://DEST" --storage-class DEEP_ARCHIVE --force-glacier-transfer
```

I don't think is possible to move them from the management console directly, after the restoration.